# Forgot to install the desktop environment while installing debian 12

Tags: linux, debian, software-installation, system-installation, desktop-environment

I forgot to install the desktop environment while installing Debian 12.

I'm stuck in tty1 when installing, no GUI, only text. I've asked on a Facebook group, and people there say I forgot to install the desktop environment.

What should I do?

Comment: If it's a fresh install, just reinstall.

Comment: `su -c apt install gnome`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Assuming you want to continue from where you are now, these instructions will help you get the graphical interface installed. However, since you are using a freshly installed system you might find it easier simply to rerun the installation from scratch, this time remembering to include the desired graphical interface.

1. Log in using the username and password you set up earlier. You will not see anything when you type in the password. No stars. Nothing. Remember to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of the username and password rather than <kbd>Tab</kbd>. You cannot use either the mouse or cursor keys at this point (if you make a mistake, delete what you've typed with <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, do not try to move back with the cursor.)

   ```
   Username: ari
   Password: _

   Linux pi 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l
   The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
   the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
   individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

   Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
   permitted by applicable law.

   ari:~$ _
   ```

   You now have a prompt (it will typically end with `$`) at which you can enter commands. I've shown the cursor as `_`. In your case it may be a flashing line or block.
2. Run `su -c tasksel` (and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>). Enter the `root` password you set for the `root` account during installation when prompted (remember you'll see nothing happen while you type the password):

   ```
   ari:~$ su -c tasksel
   Password: _
   ```

   Alternatively, if you have already installed `sudo` or definitely did not set a `root` password, try using `sudo tasksel` (and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>). Enter your password if/when prompted:

   ```
   ari:~$ sudo tasksel
   Sudo password for ari: _
   ```

   Either way, you should start the Task Selection tool, which will look something like this:

   ```
   Package configuration      
    ┌───────────────────────┤ Software selection ├────────────────────────┐
    │ You can choose to install one or more of the following predefined   │
    │ collections of software.                                            │
    │                                                                     │
    │ Choose software to install:                                         │
    │                                                                     │
    │    [*] Debian desktop environment                                   │
    │    [ ] ... GNOME                                                    │
    │    [ ] ... Xfce                                                     │
    │    [ ] ... GNOME Flashback                                          │
    │    [ ] ... KDE Plasma                                               │
    │    [ ] ... Cinnamon                                                 │
    │    [*] ... MATE                                                     │
    │    [ ] ... LXDE                                                     │
    │    [ ] ... LXQt                                                     │
    │    [ ] web server                                                   │
    │    [ ] SSH server                                                   │
    │    [ ] laptop                                                       │
    │                                                                     │
    │                                                                     │
    │                  <Ok>                      <Cancel>                 │
    │                                                                     │
    └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
   ```
3. Using the cursor keys <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> to move up and down and <kbd>Space</kbd> to select/deselect, choose the [`Debian desktop environment`](https://wiki.debian.org/DesktopEnvironment#Installation_of_a_desktop_environment). By default this will automatically include `GNOME`, but you might prefer `Cinnamon` or `MATE`. You'll see `*` alongside the two items you select.
4. Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move to the `<Ok>` item and hit <kbd>Space</kbd> once more to accept

Comment: @Ari: If you don't know how to use the command line at all yet, it might be easier to reinstall from scratch and remember to include a GUI this time, so you have a more complete system to play with while you get used to things like "command not found" meaning you might have made a typo, so you should recheck the spelling of the command someone suggested.  Also so you'll have a GUI terminal with mouse for copy/paste from web pages, or more easily look at them at the same time as you're trying stuff like tab for auto-completion.

Comment: I tried reinstalling and using hotspot and it worked to install xfce, thank you in advance

Answer (score 18):

The best way is to use `tasksel` as said [@Chris Davies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/768563/153195).

Alternatively, you can display the available desktop env by looking to Recommends packages in `apt show task-desktop`:

```
Recommends: task-gnome-desktop | task-xfce-desktop | task-kde-desktop | task-lxde-desktop | 
task-gnome-flashback-desktop | task-cinnamon-desktop | task-mate-desktop | task-lxqt-desktop,...
```

Then install the desired desktop env with its dependencies, e,g:

```
sudo apt install task-gnome-desktop
```

*Note : On Debian 12, caret `^` at the end of task-name in `apt install` isn't allowed.*

---

Using `tasksel` non interactively. To list tasks:

```
 tasksel --list-tasks

i desktop   Debian desktop environment
u gnome-desktop GNOME
u xfce-desktop  Xfce
u gnome-flashback-desktop   GNOME Flashback
u kde-desktop   KDE Plasma
u cinnamon-desktop  Cinnamon
u mate-desktop  MATE
u lxde-desktop  LXDE
u lxqt-desktop  LXQt
u web-server    web server
u ssh-server    SSH server
i laptop    laptop
```

To install:

```
sudo tasksel install gnome-desktop
```

[Debian Wiki: Installation of a desktop environment](https://wiki.debian.org/DesktopEnvironment#Installation_of_a_desktop_environment)

Comment: It says  N: unable to locate package desktop-task  N: unable to locate package desktop-task E:No packages found

Comment: @Ari `desktop-task` and `task-desktop` are not the same.

Answer (score 8):

While the above are good answers, suggest we reduce this to just:

```
sudo apt install task-desktop
```

That is it. When you are new to Linux, the default desktop is fine. It seems that Chris's excellent instructions got you logged in. Use the above command once logged in.

I am a few decades since new, and found the default desktop fine. :)

The other choices are just noise - when you are new.

(Also, I did not know about the "task-*" targets in **apt**. Thanks GAD.)